# Clear included jQuery scripts without page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, css-transitions

I'm using the Page-Transaction script (http://tympanus.net/Development/PageTransitions/) to make a website using transaction when the pages get switched.

When switching between pages, the pt-page-current gets emptied and it switched to the next page where a new html page is loaded using jQuery load(). Some pages need other jQuery scripts than other pages, that's why I only include the necessary jQuery scripts in every loaded html-page and not in the index-page (pt-page-1 has other scripts than pt-page-2).

The problem with this method is that with every page switch, all the scripts are stacked up because they keep getting implemented without refreshing the page.

Is it possible to clear included scripts (without a refresh) to implement them again when needed or are there better solutions for this problem?

```
// INDEX PAGE
<div class="pt-wrapper">
    <div class="pt-page pt-page-1 pt-page-current"> page 1 </div>
    <div class="pt-page pt-page-2"> page 2 with other jQuery scripts </div>
    <div class="pt-page pt-page-3"> page 3 "" </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Depends on your SPA (single page application) framework. A simple SPA  would need all scripts for the site loaded at the start and load partial views (sans scripts) instead.

Comment: At the moment I'm developing it using just HTML/CSS and javascript on a localhost. Would rewriting it in for example ASP.NET MVC be a solution?

Comment: MVC allows some very cool tricks with partial views (I use it myself for SPAs). It also has an SPA application type you can start with.